# When is $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Let $A$ be a ring that is not a field and $M$, $N$ modules over $A$. What conditions on $M,N$ (and maybe also on $A$) guarantee that $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is finitely generated? Is it enough to assume $M,N$ finitely generated?

Comment: Maybe you want to assume that $A$ is commutative, otherwise Hom is not an $A$-module. Or maybe you want to look at Hom as an abelian group? I think this should be clarified.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been asked before, but I cannot find it right now, so let me just answer it.

If $M$ is finitely generated, we have an epimorphism $A^n \to M$ for some $n$. This induces a monomorphism $\hom_A(M,N) \hookrightarrow \hom_A(A^n,N) = N^n$. Submodules of finitely generated modules don't have to be finitely generated (think of non-noetherian rings), but this holds by definition for noetherian modules. It is known that noetherian modules are closed under direct sums. This proves:

> If $M$ is finitely generated and $N$ is noetherian, then $\hom_A(M,N)$ is finitely generated.

In particular:

> If $A$ is noetherian and $M,N$ are finitely generated, then $\hom_A(M,N)$ is finitely generated.

Without these assumptions $\hom_A(M,N)$ doesn't have to be finitely generated:

1. If $M=A/I$ and $N=A$, then $\hom_A(M,N) \cong \mathrm{Ann}(I)$ is an ideal of $A$ which has no reason to be finitely generated when $A$ is not noetherian (Exercise: find an explicit example).
2. If $M=\oplus_{n \geq 0} A$ and $N=A$, then $\hom_A(M,N) \cong \prod_{n \geq 0} A$ is not finitely generated (unless $A=0$).

Comment: Hom is a bad boy

Comment: I am looking for a counterexample such that $hom(M,N)$ is not f.g. when $M$ and $N$ are f.g., could you give me a hint?

Comment: This is contained in my answer.

Comment: not explicitly, though

Comment: Yes but it is very easy to find an annihilator ideal which is not f.g..

Comment: maybe a quotient ring, innit?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburghello, could you please give me a reference for the second yello part you mentioned in the answer so I could learn it, please? If A is noetherian and M,N are finitely generated, then homA(M,N) is finitely generated.