# How to show $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is a finitely generated $A$-module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, modules

Let $A$ be a commutative Noetherian ring with identity and $M,N$ two finitely generated $A$-modules.

How to show $\operatorname{Hom}_A(M,N)$ is a finitely generated $A$-module?

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1366926/

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619664/when-is-operatornamehom-am-n-finitely-generated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the surjection $A^n \to M$. This induces an injection $Hom_A(M,N) \to Hom_A(A^n, N) = N^n$. So this is a submodule of a finitely generated module and by the Noetherian condition, we are done.