# Finte generation of a module $M$ and its ring of endomorphisms

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Let $M$ be an $A$-module. It is easy to see that if $M$ is a Noetherian $A$-module, then so is $\text{End}_A(M)$, its ring of endomorphisms. I'm wondering whether, in general, the two properties '$M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module' and '$\text{End}_A(M)$ is a finitely generated $A$-module' are related or not? Dietrich Burde gave me a reference (see below) which proves that even if $M$ is finitely generated, $\text{End}_A(M)$ may not be finitely generated. So the next question is what about the converse? Later i realized that the converse is false in general. For example, let $k$ be a field and $A:=k[X_1,X_2,\ldots\ ]$, the polynomial ring over $k$ in infinitely many variables. Then one can check that $\text{End}_A(m)=A$, where $m$ is the maximal ideal of $A$ generated by all the $X_i$'s. But my ring is not Noetherain. Now the question is - If $A$ is a Noetherain (or even, Artinian) ring, and $\text{End}_A(M)$ is finitely generated, does it follow that $M$ is finitely generated?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/619664/when-is-operatornamehom-am-n-finitely-generated) and let $N=M$.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, i know the Noetherian case. In the link, i couldn't find any example where $M=N$.

Comment: Without these assumptions there are counterexamples. Also for $M=N$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3438110/do-finitely-generated-modules-have-finitely-generated-endomorphism-modules). And Eric's comment explains how you obtain a counterexample, if you know one for $Hom(M,N)$. Then consider $End(M\oplus N)$. So it follows from the above duplicate.

Comment: OK, so it answers half of my question. I know examples of f.g. $A$-module $M$  such that the dual $M^*$ is not f.g. Now $\text{End}_A(M\oplus A)=A\oplus M\oplus \text{End}_A(M)\oplus M^*$, implying that $\text{End}_A(M\oplus A)$ is not f.g. But what about the converse - if $\text{End}_A(M)$ is f.g. then does it imply that $M$ is also f.g.?

Comment: By the way, thank you for the reference.